# How to handle the windows security confirmation popup using selenium c# IE 11 (windows 10)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

We recently upgrade our PC from windows 7 to windows 10 then i am trying to run my autoamtion scripts and it was failing to handle the windows security popup

```
        NavigationHelper.NavigateToUrl(ObjectRepository.Config.GetURL());

        BrowserHelper.AcceptAler();
        BrowserHelper.AcceptAler();
```

AcceptAler() method code :

Driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();

Accept alert is not working

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just install the certificate on the computer?

Comment: did you tried keyboad event to handle this pop up?

Comment: @Rock no haven't tried it . Can you explain it how to handle ?

Comment: What happened after you manually click the OK button? will it load the site? This popup occurs on your test machine. Did you check whether the same popup will also occur when your users will use this code? Generally, it is hard to handle Windows popup and it requires third-party libraries to access those Windows popups.